# не могу вычислить столетие по введенному году

Tags: java

```
centuryFromYear(int year) {
  int century;
  century = (year / 101);

return century =  (century + 1);
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Объясните словами, что делает функция `centuryFromYear`. Особенно - откуда берется число `101`.

Comment: @Igor `centuryFromYear`  создана создателями сайта на котором я учусь программировать, а `101` это для разбиения на  столетия

Comment: Функция написана "создателями" неправильно.

Comment: @Igor  Но другие же решили как то эту проблему

Comment: `int century = Math.ceil(year / 100d);` Без понятия откуда там берется 101

Comment: @Igor нужно самому написать код по заданию, а потом он проверяется сайтом  и Method написал его не правильно, а не "создатели". Теперь он просит помочь написать правильно, чтобы пройти это задание и написать сюда следующее. Так он научится программировать

Comment: @pavlofff я не правельно понял вопрос Igor "внутренности" написал я.

Comment: @Stas Dorozhko  пишет о несовместимости типов  хочет `double` но мне  нужно оставить как `int`

Comment: Вам бы про приведение типов почитать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int centuryFromYear(int year) {
  int century;
  century = (int)(Math.floor((year + 99) / 100));
  return century;
}
```

Comment: не проходит по тесту

Comment: А без библиотеки как то можно  ?

Comment: Если придумаете как округлять число без библиотеки то можно.
Как минимум приводить сразу к инту без округления, но это очень грубо

Comment: @ Bogdan Bida   Input:

year: 1700

Output:

18

 Expected Output:

17

Comment: @ Bogdan Bida не хочит  написал в коментарии віше

Comment: Странно, на сколько знаю 1700 считается началом 18го
Тогда попробуйте (int)(Math.floor((year + 99) / 100));